# Can't connect to MySQL database: No suitable driver found

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, terminal

I'm having some troubles with java and jdbc.
In particular, while my code perfectly works in a NetBeans project, when i try to execute it on a terminal or on my ubuntu vps (which is where i need it to work) i always get this exception:

`java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quakes`

First thing first: yes, i'm adding the jdbc .jar to the execute command and the compile command; Yes, i've even tried to add

`Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`,

but I always get a `ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` exception
The .jar i'm using is the exact same that i use in the NetBeans project, so i know i have the right thing, and even downloading it again from the official site won't change a thing.
Yes, the database exists, and the result doesn't change if i try to connect to another db.
I also tried switching to postgresql (yes, i didn't forget to change the url), but to no avail, it still can't find the driver.
With this, i'm guessing that the actual error is in the compile/execute commands, but even them should be ok:

`javac *.java <-cp mysql-connector-java-5.1.41-bin.jar >` (the <> parenthesis means that i tried compiling with and without specifying the classpath);

`java TAW -cp mysql-connector-java-5.1.41-bin.jar`,

In case you want to see it, here's the method that tries to connect to the database:

```
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    if (conn == null) {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+
        this.dbname,this.user,this.pass);
    }
    return conn;
}
```

Does anyone have any idea on why this happens?

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the classpath option for java before the name of your main class, otherwise it is regarded as program arguments:

```
java -cp mysql-connector-java-5.1.41-bin.jar;. TAW
```

Comment: Well.. yeah, that's true, i'm an idiot. The thing is, now it can't find the main class

Comment: you will have to add the package that contains you class to the classpath as well. Check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html for more information

Comment: See my edit, including `;.` (or `:.` if on linux) will include the local folder in the class path.

Answer (score 0):

[You can use this method step by step to create connetion.](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html#jdbc)

it is an example connectivity:

```
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    // Setup the connection with the DB
                    connect = DriverManager
                                    .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/feedback?"
                                                    + "user=sqluser&password=sqluserpw");
```